# Is there any way to create a differential equation from a set of data?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For instance, I have two animal populations that fluctuate over time, in a predator-prey relationship. I collect some data of each of the populations over a course of time. With this data is there any mathematical technique that I could use to derive a differential equation?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume a particular form for the model you might be able to fit a few parameters to the data. This tends to be rather tricky.  The kind of cycles
that you see in the standard Lotka-Volterra model are very hard to obtain in 
controlled experiments, while in natural environments there are many complicating factors (other species, weather fluctuations, etc.).